Short story in a comic about insectoid aliens approaching Earth in an invasion armada. They attack lights that turn-out to be a truck's windshield
Comic short story about insectoid alien armada approaching lights while invading Earth. Turns out to be a truck and alien fleet is smashed against truck's windshield.

"where due to a terrible miscalculation of scale the entire battle fleet was accidentally swallowed by a small dog."

https://static1.srcdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/the-far-side-comic-giant-aliens-wipe-earth-off-their-windshield.jpg
